# How can I connect to a Fedora remote desktop from Windows with putty

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, fedora, putty, remote-access

I aim to connect my fedora host running some matlab code and check its status at present. Is is it possible to connect to the host from Windows 7 machine and see the curret desktop environment as remote desktop? If it is, how could I do it? I know Putty works fine for ssh but does it for remote desktop too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's feasible - you'll need an Xserver on Windows ( [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/files/latest/download), for instance) to handle the Xserver display. You'll also need to configure putty to enable X11 forwarding.

[This post](http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html) explains how you can piece the two parts then. To summarize:

> #### Enable X11 forwarding:
>
> - Add Unix hostname
> - Switch Protocol to SSH
> - Type name of session in saved sessions
> - Click 'Save'
> - Expand the 'SSH' tab from the 'Category' list
> - Choose 'X11' from 'SSH' list
> - Check 'Enable X11 Forwarding'
>
>   [image]
> - Choose 'Session' from 'Category' list
> - Click 'Save'
>
> #### Connecting:
>
> - Start Xming
> - Start Putty
> - Double click on the saved session you want

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need full desktop access not just programs.

Comment: this is pretty much the only way with Putty, afaik. @ero